# How do I restore my project list under Package Explorer in Flash Builder (/Flex) after reinstalling OSX?

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, osx-mountain-lion, reinstall

I just did a clean install of OSX Mountain Lion today and have everything backed up (Carbon Copy Cloned) from before on another hard drive. I just reinstalled Flash Builder 4.6 and imported my preferences (keyboard shortcuts, etc). But my project list (Project Explorer view) is empty. All of the projects are in the same path as before. I'm just wondering if there is a file somewhere that holds a list of these project references that I can import or paste on my filesystem so that I don't have to manually select the projects and import them one by one.